# Namespace resource listing in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Can somebody please help me understand why is

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
```

lists resources from all namespaces but not Ingress. Even if I specify a particular namespace like the following I still don;t get the Ingress resource

```
kubectl get all -n app-space
```

Why do I have to specifically refer resource type [Ingress ] in this case If i have to get the list of all Ingress resources from all namespaces or a specific namespace

```
kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces
kubectl get ingress -n app-space
```

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl get all` is not intended to list all resources cause that would produce unexpected outputs, instead it's meant to list only some most used api resources. check the this [Pull Request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/28955#issuecomment-232652070) for the discussion.

Comment: Is `get all` undocumented outside of that PR? I couldn't find anything

Comment: if it's documented it's supposed to be here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get but it's not.